# Flutter PageRoute<T> extension changedInternalState LateError _modalBarrier

Tags: flutter, routes, initialization

I've made an extension to `PageRoute<T>` and there are a few parameters I want to change. Some of those involve getters outside BuildTransitions. I created `ValueNotifiers` however it appears that `changedInternalState` / `changedExternalState` needs to be called for these to take effect.

When I call either of these methods whether inside setState or not I get :

```
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_modalBarrier@545188637' has not been initialized.)
```

This clearly says that the `_modalBarrier` has not been initialised when the route was installed however I have not and cannot override `_modalBarrier`. `PageRoute<T>` handles this.

Why am I getting this error. I can't find anything in the docs and no required parameters are missing.